# Navigation bar pushing div down the page

Tags: html, css

Firstly, my navigation bar is causing my div to be pushed down the page leaving a white bar before the website actually starts. How do I remove this bar?

Secondly, I cannot get the svg circle to align vertically. How do I do this?

Here is my current code:

```css
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:200);
    
    body{
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
     color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    header div{
     background-image: url(http://eskipaper.com/images/sunset-dark-clouds-1.jpg);
     width: 100%;
     height: 375px;
    }
    
    header div nav ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
     padding-right: 10px;
     font-size: 25px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    header div nav ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .circular {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     border-radius: 80px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
     -moz-border-radius: 150px;
     background: url(http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg) no-repeat;
     margin-left: auto ;
     margin-right: auto ;
    }
    
    .circular img {
     opacity: 0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    
    }
```

```html
    <!-- Start of header -->
     <header id="header">
      <div>
       <!-- Start of navigation bar -->
       <nav>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#contact-wrapper">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about-wrapper">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
       <!-- End of navigation bar-->
    
       <!-- Profile picture -->
       <div class="circular">
        <!--<p id="name">Your name</p>-->
        <img src="#" alt="Me" />
       </div>
      </div>
     </header>
     <!-- End of header -->
```

Comment: @ChuckLeButt - JSFiddle usually isn't needed. Snippets tend to be a lot more useful (and the links don't break)

Comment: @ChuckLeButt - I added the snippet.

Comment: @JDB There wasn't even the full code when I wrote my comment.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt - Ah... commented within the grace period then. Earliest revision shows code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need a `<div>` inside the `<header>` since `<header>` essentially behaves the same as `<div>`.

Second, unless you're using a reset that we can't see, the `<ul>` comes with default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of about 1em. You need to reset to `margin:0`.

```css
header ul,
header ul li {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Thirdly, you can vertically center using absolute positioning and margins, since you know your element's fixed dimensions.

```css
.circular {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -100px; /* half of 200px dimension */
   margin-top: -100px; /* half of 200px dimension */
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7uubayLu/

Comment: This is the wrong answer. The circle isn't vertically centered in the parent element. *sigh*

Comment: @ChuckLeButt this answer was provided before yours ever even touched on the `.circular` question. Your `calc()` solution is not cross-browser compliant (fails in older versions of Safari, IE, Android).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like the default stylings of `<ul>` are causing the header to move down.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You should consider using a base CSS file like [Normalizer](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

As for the circle, absolute positioning is what you can use.

Place `position: relative` on the parent element.

Then add:

```css
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 100px);
left: calc(50% - 100px);
```

To `.circular`.

See the Code Snippet below...

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:200);
    
    body{
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    header div{
        background-image: url(http://eskipaper.com/images/sunset-dark-clouds-1.jpg);
        width: 100%;
        height: 375px;
      position: relative;
    }

header ul {
margin:0;
}
    
    header div nav ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    header div nav ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .circular {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 80px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
        -moz-border-radius: 150px;
        background: url(http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg) no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 100px);
        left: calc(50% - 100px);
    }
    
    .circular img {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    
    }
```

```html
<!-- Start of header -->
        <header id="header">
            <div>
                <!-- Start of navigation bar -->
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#contact-wrapper">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about-wrapper">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- End of navigation bar-->
    
                <!-- Profile picture -->
                <div class="circular">
                    <!--<p id="name">Your name</p>-->
                    <img src="#" alt="Me" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- End of header -->
```

Comment: Because your answer doesn't explain why setting the UL's margin to zero would have an impact on the parent DIV. In fact, if you use the browser's dev tools, you'll see that even the BODY tag has adopted the UL's margin.

Comment: @JDB I see. FYI: Your solution pushes the nav down further than the user intended, and doesn't address the second issue.

Comment: Yup. I'll have to brush up on my mind reading skills. I was answering the question "How do I remove this bar?", but apparently that wasn't what the OP actually wanted. As to the second question... I don't feel like answering it. I have a "one question per question" policy. :)